# How can floating islands of vegetation prevent getting beached on continental land masses?

Tags: biology, science-fiction

The title says most of it. The water-floating islands are several kilometers large, made of earth-like vegetation, but with some floating-island adaptions, like mangrove salt-tolerance and roots that intertwine horizontally to keep the island structurally sound.

Foliage may spread upwards 20-30 feet. Modified taproots grow straight downwards and into the water and secret calcium deposits around them to keep the trees from tipping over (they're heavier on the bottom than on the top, but net-buoyant).

There can be island symbiotes adapted to the islands that aid in their survival, and the plants can have additional adaptions. How might the islands prevent themselves from simply washing ashore in a strong storm?

Comment: [Sargasso Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargasso_Sea).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ocean currents that created the great Pacific Ocean Rubbish patch would seem to be the most obvious and real-world answer.

Comment: That's a really good point! I am going to use this as the main reason, and include some self-steering abilities as secondary reasons for surviving storms and remaining comfortably adrift.